# Python longest, and shortest string from the file

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to figure out the longest line and the shortest line from the file, I think I got the longest line but the shortest line doesn't come out as I think please help.

```
def longest():
    max_length = 0
max_len_line = ''
file = open("D:\PythonWorkspace\CS1400\sample.txt", "r")
for x in file:
    file = x.split('|')[0:1]
    # print(file) #Test file output

for line in file:
    if(len(line) > max_length):
        max_length = len(line)
        max_len_line = line

print(max_len_line)

def shortest():
file = open("D:\PythonWorkspace\CS1400\sample.txt", "r")

for x in file:
    file = x.split('|')[0:1]
    # print(file) #Test file output

print(min(file, key=len))


longest()
shortest()
```

Comment: The indentation is off. Please [edit] to fix it.

Comment: Your code looks like it works on *portions* of lines, not the lines themselves. So, for debugging help, you need to make a [mre] including valid code, example input, expected output, and actual output--or if you get an error, the [full error message with traceback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146/4518341). You can [edit]. If you want more tips, see [ask]. Also take the [tour] if you haven't already.

Answer (score 2):

Once you open the file you can sort the lines based on their length and get the first and last item on the list:

```py
with open("D:\PythonWorkspace\CS1400\sample.txt", "r") as file:
    sorted_lines = sorted(file.readlines(), key=lambda x: len(x))

    longest = sorted_lines[-1]
    shortest = sorted_lines[0]
```